# How to use JMeter to create a resource with POST, extract Location, and then subsequently update it with PUT

Tags: performance, web-services, rest, profiling, jmeter

I would like to profile a REST API using JMeter. I would like to write the test plan such that each user thread performs the following actions:

1. creates a new resource using HTTP POST
2. If HTTP 201 Created is received, then extract the new resource URL from the Location header of the HTTP response.
3. Subsequently update the resource using HTTP PUT
4. Loop in 3 and measure the response time

It's unclear to me how to use JMeter's conditional logic to break up the tests into these discrete parts. I would appreciate any insight anyone can provide on how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) to express this logic.

You can use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to extract Response code (In field to check, check it and extract response code in a Variable)

Use the previously extracted variable in the If Controller condition